# Unsupported pixel format of the source image when calling UnmanagedImage.FromManagedImage(Bitmap bitmap)

Tags: c#, android, bitmap, xamarin, aforge

I am creating an app which uses Portable AForge Imaging Library. I have an Android.Graphics.Bitmap image which is cast to System.Drawing.Bitmap.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap photo = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)androidPhoto;
```

Then I am trying to create UnmanagedImage BitmapData like this:

```
UnmanagedImage data = UnmanagedImage.FromManagedImage(photo);
```

This throws AForge.Imaging.UnsupportedImageFormatException: Unsupported pixel format of the source image.

I did a wide research on what causes this problem and I found out that I need a Bitmap with PixelFormat of 24bpp or 8bpp but my image's is 16bpp.
I looked for ways to convert to either 24bpp or 8bpp and I tried

```
var photo8bpp = photo.Clone (System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

and

```
var photo24bpp = photo.Clone (System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

I even tried:

```
AForge.Imaging.Image.FormatImage (ref photo);
```

My last try was this convertion method:

```
private System.Drawing.Bitmap Convert(System.Drawing.Bitmap oldbmp) 
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) 
    {
        oldbmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        ms.Position = 0;
        return (System.Drawing.Bitmap)(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms));
    }
}
```

Everything I tried led to this:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object   at at (wrapper unknown)
>   ImagePixelEnumerator.Helpers.Pixels.NonIndexed.PixelDataRgb565:PtrToStructure
>   (intptr,object)   at at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal:PtrToStructure
>   (intptr,System.Type)   at
>   ImagePixelEnumerator.Helpers.Pixel.ReadRawData (IntPtr imagePointer)
>   [0x00000] in d:\Users\Anders\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\aforge\Sources\System.Drawing\Helpers\Pixel.cs:272

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, I am the maintainer of Portable AForge. I need to check this particular call under Android, and I will get back with analysis results later on. But just to check, what is your purpose of converting to `UnmanagedImage`? Are you not able to obtain the same results with a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` or `System.Drawing.Image` from the *Shim.Drawing* library that you eventually cast to an `Android.Graphics.Bitmap`?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson The edge detection functions in AForge require an 8BPP image to work correctly.  You can cast an Android Bitmap to a System.Drawing.Bitmap just fine, but the AForge function to convert to grayscale throws an error if you try to use the converted bitmap as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I think I fixed it:

```
var data = new UnmanagedImage(androidPhoto.LockPixels(), androidPhoto.Width,
            androidPhoto.Height, androidPhoto.Width,  
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```